# solve the ode $-y''y+1=(y')^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

solve the ode $$-y''y+1=(y')^2$$ 
I tried to use:   $$p=y$$  and      $$pp'=y''$$ 
then got $$p'y=\frac{1}{p}-p$$ and did not know what to do next..

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite as: $$1= y''y+y'^2 = (yy')'\implies yy' = x+c$$

so $$(y^2)' = 2x+2c\implies \boxed{y^2 = x^2+2xc+d}$$

so it is a branch of some hyperbola

Answer (score 0):

At this point you have a separable first order ODE (note that $p=p(y)$) that can be solved by separation of variables
$$
\int\frac{p\,dp}{1-p^2}=\frac{dy}{y}\implies 1-p^2=\frac{C}{y^2}\\\text{ or }y^2-(yy')^2=C
$$
so that with $u=y^2$
$$
4u-u'^2=4C
$$
which is autonomous and thus separable for both signs in the square root.